# 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified' if using Alias in Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Until recently, the following SQL statement worked without any problems using a MSSQL database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Flights.MODEL_ID,
                Pilots.NAME,
                Models.DESCRIPTION,
                Flights.KURSLAENGE * 4828 * Flights.DREIECKE + Flights.SPEED AS POINTS,
                Flights.SPEED,
                Flights.DREIECKE * Flights.KURSLAENGE * 0.0048284            AS DISTANZ,
                Flights.FLIGHT_ID,
                Pilots.PILOT_ID,
                Flights.STARTZEIT,
                Flights.DREIECKE,
                Flights.CATEGORY_ID,
                Pilots.VORNAME,
                Flights.KURSLAENGE,
                Flights.PLACE_ID
FROM   Flights
       INNER JOIN Models
         ON Flights.MODEL_ID = Models.MODEL_ID
       INNER JOIN Pilots
         ON Models.PILOT_ID = Pilots.PILOT_ID
WHERE  ( Flights.STARTZEIT <= @DateMax )
GROUP  BY Pilots.NAME,
          Models.DESCRIPTION,
          Flights.KURSLAENGE * 4828 * Flights.DREIECKE + Flights.SPEED,
          Flights.MODEL_ID,
          Flights.SPEED,
          Flights.DREIECKE * Flights.KURSLAENGE * 0.0048284,
          Flights.FLIGHT_ID,
          Pilots.PILOT_ID,
          Flights.STARTZEIT,
          Flights.DREIECKE,
          Flights.CATEGORY_ID,
          Pilots.VORNAME,
          Flights.KURSLAENGE,
          Flights.PLACE_ID
HAVING ( Flights.CATEGORY_ID = @CatId )
       AND ( Flights.STARTZEIT >= @DateMin )
ORDER  BY POINTS DESC
```

Now I get the error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified

Replacing 'ORDER BY POINTS DESC' with eg 'ORDER BY Flights.SPEED DESC' also works.

What could be the reason, that the above statement is not working anymore?

Comment: Looks like it should work. What `@@version`?

Comment: The error message says it all, when SELECT DISTINCT only select list columns may be specified in the ORDER BY.

Comment: @jarlh - They **are** only specifying a selected column in the `order by`. They are ordering by `POINTS` and that is one of their selected columns.

Comment: It's a little difficult to read this - are there any columns different between your `SELECT` list and your `GROUP  BY` clause? If not, how/why do you expect it to produce non-distinct results, even without `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @MartinSmith, missed that part - didn't right scroll...

Comment: Why SELECT DISTINCT combined with that GROUP BY? Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions?

Comment: For the actual question, "What could be the reason...", the only one I can think of is a version upgrade. But that's a pretty large change to have had happened and for you to not mention in the question. I know that there have been changes where `ORDER BY` processing has become more strict between successive versions but cannot point to a specific pair of versions where this query would succeed on the earlier but not the latter - as Martin says, it looks like it *should* work, so it needs more investigating/isolating on your side.

Comment: Is it tables or views you're selecting from? And does any of the tables/views have a native POINTS column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, changed compability level is another possibility

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. My provider just informed me, that they upgraded the SqlServer zu 2012. This might be the source of the problem. 
Does anyone have a solution to change the query to meet the requirements (sorry, I'm not an SQL expert):
- The list must include evey pilots.Name only once
- The list must be sorted according the POINTS